# Sortable nested group error

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery sortable on an element but when I drop down an element under other he set him as a child. Check please this behaviour to demonstrate: http://recordit.co/w8c5oXbnq4

Using https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

I'm using sortable like this:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    group: 'nested',
    handle: 'i.cat-move',
```

How can i set right behaviour without being a child? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your gif not work

Comment: Sorry bad copy paste, now its working

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution, i need to push a little bit to the left when drag elements.
Please check this gif demonstration: http://recordit.co/XDtnk17Hhm

Thanks
Carlos Vieira